# Installing an perl based web-app in extremely restricted environment

Tags: perl

*Because i have a long series of comments with @ikegami, I cleaning up the question, in a hope it will be more understandable. Unfortunately, english isn't my "main" language. :(*

Let say, having an environment where:

- no development tools are installed (no `make`, nor `gcc` or like)
- `perl` is *installed* with its *core packages*, nothing more
- no outgoing network access is allowed - e.g. the user couldn't use `curl` nor `cpan` to download/install perl dependencies
- the user even doesn't have admin (root) rights
- but want install and evaluate some perl based web-app, let call it as `MyApp`

The `MyApp`

- doesn't uses any XS-based module. (at least, I hope - in the development me using `plenv` and `cpanm`, so never checked the installed dependencies in depth)
- it is an pure PSGI app, the simple `plackup app.psgi` works OK
- the app uses some data-files which should be included in the "deployment".

**The main question is:** *how to prepare the `MyApp`, and the all used CPAN-modules, to be **easily** installed in such restricted environment?*

The goal is:

- i don't need save *my* efforts and *my* time
- but i want save the user's time and want minimize the needed actions on his side, so the installation (deployment) should be simple-as-possible.

E.g. how to get an running web-app to the user's machine with minimum possible (his) steps.
- the simplest thing is could be something as:
  - copy one file (zip, or tarbal)
  - unpack it
  - from the terminal execute some `run.pl` in the unpacked directory.

To get the above simple installation, my idea was the following:

1.) Create an tarball, and after the unpacking will contain 3 folders and 1 perl-script, let say:

```
myapp_repo/
myapp_repo/distlib   #will contain all MyApp's perl modules also ALL used CPAN modules and their dependecies
myapp_repo/datafiles #will contain app-specific data files and such
myapp_repo/install.pl
myall_repo/lib   #will contain modules directly used by the `install.pl`
```

2.) I will develop an `install.pl` script, and it will be used as the *installer-tool*, like

```
perl install.pl new /path/to/app_root
```

and it will (should):

- create the all needed directories under the `/path/to/app_root` (especially the `lib` where the will install the perl modules)
- will call "local" `cpanm` internally (from the `myapp_repo/lib`) to install the app's perl modules and their CPAN dependencies using only distribution files from the `distlib`.
- will generate and install the needed runtime script and the `app.psgi` into the `/path/to/app_root/bin`
- will install the needed data-files for the app.

3.) So, after this the user should be able to simply run:

```
/path/to/app_root/bin/plackup /path/to/app_root/bin/app.psgi
```

In short, the user should use:

- the system-wide perl and the system-wide perl-core modules
- and any other

  - runtime perl-scripts (like `plackup`)
  - and the required CPAN-modules
- should be installed to an self-contained directory tree using only files (no net-access).

E.g. the `install.pl` should somewhat call internally the `cpanm` to achieve (as equivalent) for the following `cpanm` command

```
cpanm --mirror file://path/to/myapp_repo/distlib --mirror-only My::App
```

which, should install `My::App` and all dependencies **without** network access using only the files from the `myapp_repo/distlib`

Some questions:

- Is possible to use `cpanm` (called as an locally installed module) without the `make`?
- For creating the `myapp_repo/distlib`, me thinking about using [Pinto](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pinto). Is it the right tool for achieve the above?
- forgot me something? or with other words:
- Is the above an viable (read: working) way?
- are are any other tools, which i could/should to use for simplifying the creation of such distribution tarball?

@ikegami suggesting some method:
- "install everything" in one fresh-directory on my machine
- transfer this self-contained directory to the target machine

It sound very good, because this directory could contain all the needed app-specific data-files too, unfortunately, I don't understand the details how his solution should be done.

The FatPacked solution looks interesting too - need learn about it.

Comment: [App::FatPacker](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::FatPacker) will combine your script and all prerequisite modules (if they're not XS) into a single runnable perl file.

Comment: @ikegami yes. :) this is the best way. Unfortunately, this isn't possible - by the policy.

Comment: @ikegami maybe me forgot something more to describe the environment, (besides the - no root access), but simply think about as: it isn't possible to install the any compiler. :( Unfortunately, otherwise i would use `plenv` and few simple scripts. :(

Comment: @jm666 What part of the policy would prohibit a FatPacked application?

Comment: @duskwuff the FatPacked approach sound interesting and could solve the whole problem. Me doesn't knows it enough (yet), so need learn about it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't write your own `make` or installer. Just copy it `make` from a different machine (which is basically what `apt`/`yum`/etc do anyway, and which you'd have to do even if you wrote your own). You'd be able to use `cpan` in 5 minutes!

Also, that should allow you to install `gcc` if you need it (e.g. to install an XS module), although it doesn't sound like you do. If you do install `gcc`, I'd install my own `perl` to avoid having to deal with `PERL5LIB`.

Tools such as [`minicpan`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/minicpan) will allow you to install any module from CPAN without internet access. Of course, you can keep using the command you are already using it if mirrors the packages you need.

---

The above explains how to simply and quickly setup a machine so it can use `cpan` and thus install *any* module easily.

If you just want to install a specific module and its dependencies, you can completely avoid using `cpan` on the target machine. First, you need a fresh install of Perl (preferable of the same version as the one on the target system). Then, simply install the module to a fresh dir on your machine, and transfer that dir to the target machine. That's it; nothing else needs to be done. This even works for XS modules if the two machine are similar enough.

This is what `ppm` (ActiveState's Perl package manager) does.

Unfortunately, while this solution is almost as simple as the one above, it's not nearly as flexible, it doesn't run the test suite of the modules being installed, etc. It does have the advantage of not requiring the transfer of any binary (if you're not installing any XS modules).

Comment: Typical answer from an perl-guru. Perl is great, just do everything yourself. (pull everything using minicpan). But the truth is: in the real world, users uses pre-packaged perl modules from the Linux-distriubutions, because using cpan is **prohibited**. (regardles of why).  Definitely _would be nice to have_ some longer tutorial how to package and deploy apps for such environments.

Comment: @cajwine, It's like you read neither the question nor the answer!?!?! 1) i said the very opposite, use existing tools rather than rolling out your own. 2) The OP isn't prohibited from using `cpan`. 3) Before his edit, it sounded like he wanted to installs module himself. 4) I did give instructions for making pre-packaging the module. This isn't normally a portable solution -- something the OP requested -- but it is in this situation.